# How to mirror Sharepoint 2007 site?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, replication, mirroring

I'm not sure if this should be posted here or over stackoverflow, but how does one go about mirroring a Sharepoint 2007 site? I have admin access, and the mirror doesn't need to be nice and pretty; it just needs to be presentable and readable. Also, I need all the shared docs to be copied as well.

We use to have WinHTTrack to mirror the Sharepoint, but that broke a few months ago due to some of our recent security changes. I tried the username@password:domain method but that resulted no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In what context and for what purpose?

Using HTTrack suggest you were offloading the pages for viewing on a less capable system. Besides HTTrack there are other "web grabbers" around, Firefox has a few extensions, which may get you around your security issues with running HTTrack.

There isn't a "SharePoint" way to duplicate this (to non SharePoint sites that is). However, if you just need the site in an additional location within the SharePoint ecosphere there are multiple methods:

1. Utilize the Powershell tools to backup or extract your site and import it into another SharePoint deployment (or the same one in a different location for that matter).  These can be used with the OS scheduler to create regular copies.
2. Use the content deployment tools to "push" content into another site on the same or different farm
3. Use Database Mirroring / TLOG Shipping to get the data to another farm.

Now the above could be "live" or "static" depending on your configuration.  You can lock a Site Collection or set a database to "read only'.

There are "connectors" for various other content management systems, like Dot Net Nuke that will get your content out of SharePoint, however I don't know of any that are "free', and certainly none that will work directly out of the box without some work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the backup of the existing sharepoint site and content database and restore the both in the new site. Usually Doc lib are stored in the content database. so restoring the content database will help u to restore the doc lib as well. 
If you are a part of farm administrator group member, you can even take the backup of doc lib alone. So that you can take site and doc lib backup and restore it in the new site, this will save time and effort.

Correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'll need the mirror to be more or less static. Would this method work?